# Drag n Drop in old browsers Vs modern browsers

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

In some tutorials (made more than year) about **drag and drop**, and in displaying the results in those tutorials, the dragged element follow the cursor.

**Example from a tutorial:**

[image]

But actual browsers (Firefox & Chrome) behave in a different way during dragging, and nothing follow the cursor.

**Simple Example:**

```js
        document.querySelectorAll('.drop').forEach(el => {
            el.addEventListener('dragover', event => {
                event.preventDefault();
            });
            el.addEventListener('drop', event => {
                event.preventDefault();
                el.appendChild(document.querySelector(`#${event.dataTransfer.getData('item_id')}`));
            });
        });
        
        document.querySelectorAll('.drag').forEach(el => {
            el.addEventListener('dragstart', event => {
                event.dataTransfer.setData('item_id', el.id);
            });
        });
```

```html
    <div class="drop" style="padding:20px; background-color: #F3F3F3; margin: 25px 0px; width: 60%">
        <div id="item_1" class="drag" draggable="true" style="width:100px; height:100px; background-color: blueviolet;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="drop" style="padding:20px; background-color: #F3F3F3; margin: 25px 0px; width: 60%"></div>
```

**My question :** What is the property responsible for following the cursor during dragging elements and how to configure it ?

**EDIT :** This what i have during dragging in my browser (Firefox & Chrome)

[image]

**EDIT 2 :** I fix the "problem", it was the windows 7 basic theme, i switch it to windows 7 default theme and :

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "following the cursor"? When I drag the element in your code example it gets moved around underneath the cursor.

Comment: @Mike, i added what i have as result in the question

Comment: It doesn't look like that for me. I see the purple box moving around. Maybe it's a browser setting, or something specific to your OS.

Comment: Thank you @Mike, i will check for that.

Comment: @Mike, the problem comes from windows 7 basic theme. Thanks again.

Comment: Interesting. I'm glad you found your answer.